# Using Firebase, is it possible to export email addresses of app users who perform a certain action?

Tags: firebase

I am fairly new to Firebase and I'm wondering if I can use it to help target our email communications by activity.

For example, I want to be able to segment my users by those who have / have not used the app in the last month, and export their email addresses as a list.

Is this achievable with Firebase?

Comment: Yes, check this website. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron
Instead of deleting you can create a list and save somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase it's common practice to have a /users node that stores more information about the user than the Firebase authentication server does.

So for example

```
users
  uid_0
    email: "person@thing.com"
    fav_food: "pizza"
    login_timestamp: "20170215"
  uid_1
    email: "anotherperson@thing.com"
    fav_food: "tacos"
    login_timestamp: "20170320"
```

With this, you can easily query for users who have not logged in in the last 30 days by taking todays date (the ending date), go back 30 days to obtain a starting date and query for all of the users whose last login was from 0 to the date 30 days ago.

```
usersRef.queryBy("login_timestamp").queryStarting(at: "00000000")
                                   .queryEnding(at: "20170223")
```

I don't know your platform so the above code is conceptual.

The result of this is the uid_0 node since their last login was more than 30 days ago

Once you have the data from the query, the email addresses are easily exportable in the language of your choice.

Comment: Could this be extended to logging when they have performed a certain action in-app, e.g. viewed a certain page?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JStan Yes - it's very expandable. You just need to write the timestamp when the action occurs - very similar to writing the timestamp when they log in. So for example, if the user prints something you could write *print_timestamp: 170324134500* and you will have a record of when the print event occurred.